# How to get actual value from CSV file instead exponential value

Tags: csv

I am facing a problem with exponential value (eg:1.4588E+12). As per my requirement I need to read data from CSV file which is having exponential values. I need to have exact value instead of exponential. In my application I am getting Microsoft Excel file, when I am updating the data like number which is having morethan 15 digits and saving as .csv file this value saving like 1.4588E+12 instead of 1458795648552. To read this CSV file I am using opencsv.jar. Is there any way to get actual value while reading CSV file?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. Excel uses [double precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) to represent numbers.  This format has 52 explicit bits in the significand plus 1 implied bit, for a total of 53 bits, which is almost enough to represent any 16 decimal digit number, but not all (53 log10(2) ≈ 15.955).  So be aware that not all 16 decimal digit numbers maintain full precision in Excel.
2. When you export from Excel to CSV numbers that are formatted as numbers (instead of text) Excel will choose scientific notation for large numbers, and you will likely lose precision as not all significant digits are written out, when this happens there is nothing you can do when reading the CSV file to recover those lost digits.  You should format the column with these numbers as text before saving as CSV.
3. Let's say you have a number that is 16 decimal digits and it **is** representable in double precision floating point, and you saved it as text... you have not lost precision in storing the number as CSV.  However, Excel will only take the first 15 digits of your number when it imports from CSV (I don't know about opencsv.jar) any other digits are set to zero.

One way to solve this would be to add two more columns in Excel, and represent the number divided by 1E8 (the upper 8 decimal digits) in one column and the number modulo 1E8 (the lower 8 decimal digits) in the other column.  You then multiply the first column by 1E8 and add the second column after reading the CSV file to recover the original number.

Here is an example, using Google docs but should be similar in Excel:

These are the formulas I used to split the number in A1 into B1 and C1 then join again in D1

[image: These are the formulas I used to split the number in A1 into B1 and C1 then join again in D1]

This is what the values look like, notice cell D1 has the reconstructed value in cell A1

[image: This is what the values look like]

You might be able to hide columns B and C but still have them exported to the CSV.  That way the person filling out the spreadsheet isn't aware that the number in column A is being manipulated in columns B and C.  You don't need column D, I put it there just so you could see how the number in column A can be recovered from the values in columns B and C.

Comment: But I dont have scope to change format of excel data before saving it to csv. Is there any API support  to do this automatically.

Comment: @vaitla not sure what you mean, you do not have access to the excel spreadsheet or you would like more details on how to make the change?  I do not have Excel, but I can show you on Google doc spreadsheet how to make an equivalent change.

Comment: Yes, I am getting excel data.I have access to do changes in excel file(this will contain customer contact details like PhNo etc).My application expecting CSV file as input file to read these contact details into application. If i update contact No from 10 decimal digits to 15 digits it is converting to scientific format. I can change this format in excel but that is not recommended to do manually as end user may not aware of these manual changes. Is there any mathematical process to get back scientific format to decimal format? If this psbl I can do it in java code while reading it from CSV.

Comment: Well, the problem is, using your example, if the CSV file contains "1.4588E+12" then you only have 5 decimal digits of precision "1.4588" you have lost the lower 8 digits of "1458795648552", and Excel has rounded the '7' to an '8'... so information has been lost, there is no way to recover "95648552" from the CSV if it isn't there.

Comment: So the solution is to make sure the CSV has all the digits, either in the same column (by storing the number as text) or by adding another 2 columns, one with a formula that grabs the upper 8 decimal digits and another that grabs the lower 8 decimal digits... you piece it back together after you read the CSV.